# MATLAB wavread N1 N2 Values

Tags: matlab, speech-recognition, speech

I am a newbie to MATLAB and have a question.

In the MATLAB `wavread` function:

```
wavread(filename, [N1 N2]);
```

Can anyone please help me understand why the `N1` & `N2`indices are usually chosen as 24120 & 25439 respectively for slicing the `wav` file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you read the help carefully, here : http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/wavread.html you will see "wavread(filename, [N1 N2]) returns only samples N1 through N2 from each channel in the file." It means that you want to read from sample N1 to sample N2, not the whole file.

Comment: Thanks NKN for replying. Yes, have seen the documentation. However, couldn't figure out why N1 & N2 are usually chosen as 24120 & 25439 in a lot of speech recognition MATLAB programs. Not sure if it's because this slice of the sample contains specific speech related info that helps in recognition. Please help.

Comment: "in a lot of speech recognition MATLAB programs" - which ones? Are they perhaps all using the same sample data set?

Answer (score 1):

If you consult the [`wavread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/wavread.html) documentation, it's actually quite clear on what `N1` and `N2` are.  `N1` represents the beginning sample and `N2` represents the ending sample, and what is returned are your audio samples between `N1` and `N2` for each channel.

As such, supposing your audio sampling rate was 44100 Hz.  Following your post, if you did:

```
wavread(filename, [24120 25439])  ,
```

you are returning audio samples for each channel that range between the 0.5469 (`24120/44100`) second to 0.5768 (`25439/44100`) second mark in your audio file.  This would return an overall matrix of `1320 x N` where `N` is the number of audio channels in your file.  The overall length of this audio sample file would be roughly 0.03 seconds.

BTW, these indices are **not usually chosen to be this way**.  These indices are highly dependent on the length of your audio signal, as well as what you want to isolate from the audio signal itself.  These indices are used to mainly to disregard irrelevant audio signal data and to only give you those audio samples where you know there is some meaningful output.

My belief is that the audio files that you are processing have very meaningful output between these time frames, which is why those indices are used quite often.  As I said, this all depends on which audio files you are processing.